# Two problems. Not adding to next index in array and not removing from array

Tags: java, arrays, oop, for-loop, if-statement

The problem I have encountered is as follows:  I have created two array representing docking spaces for ships. The first array the ship object (shipName and size - usually Super-Container) be saved in the array and if there is no space then it will be added to a waiting list array. If the space in the first array becomes vacant then the ship from the waiting list will join the first array.

But when I go to undock (remove a ship from the first array) it only finds the ship in index 0 of the first array and not index 1, 2 etc.

Also, I can only add one ship to the waiting list and it says it is full.
Can you help? Here's my dock class, problem in undock() and waitingList():

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Ship[] dock1 = new Ship[10];
private static Ship[] waitingList = new Ship[10];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu();
}

public static void menu() {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Choose an option: 1-3");
        System.out.println("1. Dock");
        System.out.println("2. Undock");
        System.out.println("3. Status");

        int menu = scan.nextInt();
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("1. Dock");
                dock();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("2. Undock");
                undock();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("3. Status");
                printDock();
                printWaitingList();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("4. Exit");
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("No such option");
                break;
        }
    }
}


public static void dock() {

    System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
    String size = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the ships dock:");
    //Check if the dock number is valid
    int i = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
    if (i >= 0 && i < 10 && dock1[i] == null) {
        int c = 0;
        int co = 0;
        int sco = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < dock1.length; j++) {
            if (dock1[j] != null &&         dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Cargo")) {
                c++;
            }
            if (dock1[j] != null && dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Container")) {
                co++;
            }
            if (dock1[j] != null && dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Super-Container")) {
                sco++;
            }
        }

        if (c < 10 && co < 5 && sco < 2) {
            //Add ship to the dock
            dock1[i] = new Ship(name, size);
            System.out.println("Enough space you can dock");
            System.out.println("Ship has been docked");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot dock");
            waitingList(name,size);
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Couldn't dock");
        waitingList(name, size);
    }

}


public static void undock() {
    System.out.println("Status of ships: ");
    printDock();
    System.out.println("Enter ship's name to undock: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    //System.out.println("Enter ship's size to undock: ");
   // String size = scan.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++) {
        if (dock1[i] != null && dock1[i].getShipName().equals(name)) {
            dock1[i] = null;
            System.out.println("Ship removed");
            /// HERE CHECK IF SHIP IN DOCK
            for (int j = 0; j < waitingList.length; j++) {
                if (dock1[i] == null) {
                    // Add ship to the dock
                    dock1[i] = new Ship(waitingList[j].getShipName(), waitingList[j].getShipSize());
                    System.out.println("Move ship from waiting list to dock 1");
                    waitingList[j] = null;
                   break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No space in dock1");
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ship not docked here");
            break;
        }

    }

}

public static void waitingList(String name, String size){
    System.out.println("Dock 1 is full, ship will try to be added to Waiting List");
    for (int i = 0; i < waitingList.length; i++) {
        if (waitingList[i] == null) { //CHANGE TO ALLOW MORE THAN ONE SHIP
            //Add ship to the dock
            waitingList[i] = new Ship(name, size);
            System.out.println("Enough space added to waiting list");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No space on waiting list, ship turned away");
            return;
        }
    }

}


public static void printDock() {

    System.out.println("Docks:");

    for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++) {
        if (dock1[i] == null) {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + dock1[i].getShipName() + " " + dock1[i].getShipSize());
        }
    }
}

private static void printWaitingList() {

    System.out.println("Waiting List:");

    for (int i = 0; i < waitingList.length; i++) {
        if (waitingList[i] == null) {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + waitingList[i].getShipName() + " " + waitingList[i].getShipSize());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this sounds so much easier if you used a map or something, why would you not send undock your array as a parameter and then return an array, same for all your methods

Comment: Unfamiliar with using a map. I need to do it this way just looking for solutions to these two problems thanks

Comment: you should be passing the array in methods (dock, undock) and returning the updated state. It would be much more easier/cleaner/readable that way.

Comment: How would this look?

Answer (score 1):

Your loops are only working with first element of the array, becouse when check failed (for example `if (waitingList[i] == null)` in `waitingList`) you print error, and then return, thus breaking loop. What you need to do is make `boolean dockSuccessful = false`, then if condition is met (there is space in dock) you set it to `true` and then `break` the loop (so you woudn't dock ship multiple times). After the loop you insert

```
if(!dockSuccessful) {
    System.out.println("Some error message here");
}
```

So, if loop finds at least one empty dock, `dockSuccessful` would be `true`, and error would not be printed. But if it checked all the docks, it will not update `dockSuccessful`, it would still be `false`, and error will be printed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did try this and it didn't work